# Unable to STOP microsoft sharepoint foundation web application service

Tags: web-services, 2013

I have a multi server farm and I want to stop "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service" in all the other servers except Web Front End server.

When i tried stopping this service it switched to "STOPPING" status and nothing seems to happen.

[image: This is how it looks]

I tried IISRESET and server restart. Did not work.

Comment: Try this: > stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice

Comment: stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice - helped me

Answer (score 13):

Try these commands if you haven't already,

```
 stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

[Source](http://kb4sp.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/restarting-the-sharepoint-foundation-web-services-service-on-the-wfe-to-bring-back-a-missing-iis-url/)

Or using PowerShell,

```
$server = "win-lhg69g3kdb2"
$service = Get-SPServiceInstance -Server $server | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}
$service | Stop-SPServiceInstance -confirm:$false > $null
while(-not ($service.Status -eq "Disabled")){
    write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $service.Status; sleep 5;
    $service = Get-SPServiceInstance -Server $server | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}
}
Get-SPServiceInstance -Server $server | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"} | Start-SPServiceInstance -confirm:$false > $null
```

[Source](http://bramnuyts.be/2011/03/31/restart-sharepoint-2010-service-through-powershell/)

Or try,

```
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

This [Scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2674684?wa=wsignin1.0) might help too.

If nothing of above works then use [ULS Viewer](http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint.html) to identify the main cause of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to wait after you issue

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

it takes a long time to complete if you have many web applications.

Comment: can this command be used in powershell - sharepoint 2013